# Provider did not return a DbSpatialServices instance

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm having a problem with Entity Framework and retrieving data from the database.
I got a table. This table contains a field with the geography type.
When I run my code:

```
IEnumerable<Locatie> a = locatiezoeker.Locaties.Where(x => x.siteId == geselecteerdeWebsiteId);
```

I get the following error:

> Exception: System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException
>   Message: The provider did not return a DbSpatialServices instance.
>   Source: System.Data.Entity
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetDbSpatialDataReader(DbDataReader fromReader, String manifestToken)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetSpatialDataReader(DbDataReader fromReader, String manifestToken)
>      at System.Data.Spatial.SpatialHelpers.CreateSpatialDataReader(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbDataReader reader)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.b__d[TProperty](DbDataReader reader, Int32 column)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetSpatialPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName, PrimitiveTypeKind spatialTypeKind)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>      at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>      at MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
>      at ImportManager.LeegDatabaseVoorGeselecteerdeWebsite(Guid geselecteerdeWebsiteId) in d:\web\ImportManager.cs:line 461
>      at VerwerkCsv() in d:\web\ImportTool.aspx.cs:line 204

I updated my edmx (in fact I regenerated it). I updated my NuGet package. I'm running .NET 4.5. See the snippet of my packages.config

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Does anybody have any idea where this is going wrong? I cannot find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was Glimpse causing all the trouble:
https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/371.
I used GlimpseEF5 1.2.0. In version 1.3.1 this problem is fixed